# SQL SELECT is not a number but can be NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, null

I have got a table with 3 columns: (int) `test1`, (int) `test2` and (int) `test3`. The content is an integer or `NULL`.

For example:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ test1      ║ test2       ║ test3       ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ 123        ║ 456         ║ NULL        ║
║ 2 ║ 456        ║ 456         ║ NULL        ║
║ 3 ║ NULL       ║ NULL        ║ NULL        ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I want to get every entry, where `test1` is not "123" and `test2` is not "123" and `test3` is not "123". I need every entry with another number than "123" or `NULL`.

I tried the following SQL syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE test1 != "123" AND test2 != "123" AND test3 != "123";
```

The problem is, that I get no entry because there must be a number everywhere. In this example, I want to get entry 2 and entry 3 but not the first one because there is a "123" in column `test1`.

How can I make this?

Comment: you realize that in your example you would get no row that has all three fields not null or different than 123 --edit sorry should have looked at the last two lines instead of stucking on vocabulary

Comment: @user3802077 That's what the question is about.

Comment: You can't check for nulls by equality checks: that's the important part of your confusion. Try looking at `is null` and null logic after you find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`null` is not a value - it's the lack thereof. It returns "unknown" when used in any context expecting a value, even the `!=` operator. In order to handle `null`s, you should do so explicitly with the `is` operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable
WHERE  (test1 IS NULL OR test1 != 123) AND 
       (test2 IS NULL OR test2 != 123) AND
       (test3 IS NULL OR test3 != 123)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation and the sql code. It helped a lot and solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

Use `ifnull()` to convert nulls to an included number:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE ifnull(test1, 0) != "123"
AND ifnull(test2, 0) != "123"
AND ifnull(test3, 0) != "123";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use isnull(column, 0). I assume the columns are integer:

```
create table #x (test1 int null, test2 int null, test3 int null)
go
insert #x select 123, 456, null
insert #x select 456, 456, null
insert #x select null, null, null

SELECT * FROM #x WHERE isnull(test1,0) != 123 AND isnull(test2,0) != 123 AND isnull(test3,0) != 123


test1       test2       test3       
----------- ----------- ----------- 
        456         456        NULL 
       NULL        NULL        NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the NOT IN function and is NULL function:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (test1 not in ("123","others") or test1 is NULL)
and  (test2 not in ("123","others") or test2 is NULL)
```

And so on...
You can add whatever you want to exclude from the NOT IN list.

Answer (score 0):

Should work with this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (test1 != "123" OR test1 is null) 
 AND  (test2 != "123" OR test2 is null)
 AND  (test3 != "123" OR test3 is null);
```